# Changing HttpRequestMessage request URI inside the code is not chaning in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have HttpClient registered in `Program.cs`

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("group", (service, client) =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7003/api/");
            
    var store = service.GetRequiredService<TokenStore>();
    
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", store.Jwt);
});
```

And in `razor file` I have this method:

```cs
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ChatNameIdModel>> GetChats(string jwt)
    {
        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("group");
        
        var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, client.BaseAddress + "groups/me");

        requestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {jwt}");
        
        var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
        
        var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var chats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChatNameIdModel>>(responseBody);

        return chats!;
    }
```

I changed the `client.BaseAddress + "groups/me"` the address to be `client.BaseAddress + "group/all/me"` but the Blazor seems to not applying my changes.

[image]

Whats wrong? Is this cached somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

In your Razor component, you can inject the IHttpClientFactory and use it to create the
HttpClient:

```
@inject IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory

@code {
    private async Task<IEnumerable<ChatNameIdModel>> GetChats(string jwt)
    {
        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("group");

        var response = await client.GetAsync("groups/me");
        
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var chats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChatNameIdModel>>(responseBody);

        return chats!;
    }
}
```

In the code above, I've simplified the process by using the **GetAsync** method directly on the client with the relative path, as the base address is already set when configuring the **HttpClient**. Also, I added **response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();** to ensure that the request was successful.

Make sure you're passing the correct **jwt** parameter to the **GetChats** method when calling it.
I hope this helps.